# How to solve $x^3-x^2-8x+12$ with Cardano's formula?

Tags: polynomials, cubics

I'm trying to solve this and I have a mistake somewhere, but I don't know where. I calculated the rational roots with Rolle's theorem, so I know, that I should get $-3$ and $2$ somehow.

So, first of all. I tried to write $x^3-x^2-8x+12$ as the polynomial of $x-1$. I used Horner's method to divide the original polynomial with $x-1$.

So my result is $(x-1)^3-8(x-1)-4$. Which doesn't seem to be equal to the first polynomial. 
Could you help me, please?

Comment: use wolfram alpha without hesitation or shame

Comment: I suggest that _if_ you want to write your polynomial as a polynomial of $x-1$, then insert $x+1$ in your original polynomial and expand. You get $(x+1)^3-(x+1)^2-8(x+1)+12=x^3+2x^2-7x+4$, and hence your original polynomial is $(x-1)^3+2(x-1)^2-7(x-1)+4$.

Comment: wtf is a Horner table and why do you guys confuse "dividing by $(x-1)$" with  "rewriting the polynomial in terms of $(x-1)$"

Comment: Maybe, you don't want to write your polynomial in terms of $(x-1)$, but in terms of $(x-1/3)$? And, @mercio, why so upset? :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the cubic formula, it's easier to derive the result from first principles. When the equation is specified with numerical values for the coefficients, this is easier because numerical values can be added up, multiplied etc.. But if the coefficients are symbols then the expressions are going to grow in size by some factor in each step. This is why the general solution for N linear equations with N unknowns is unwieldy for N larger than 3, yet you won't find it a big deal to solve ten equations with ten unknowns using Gaussian elimination, if the coefficients are numerical quantities.

To solve 3rd degree equation, you should get rid of the quadratic term by putting$ x = y + 1/3$:

$$x^3 - x^2 - 8 x + 12 = y^3  -\frac{25}{3}y + \frac{250}{27}$$

Then we invoke the identity:

$$(A+B)^3 = A^3+ 3 A^2B +3 AB^3 + B^3$$

which we can write as:

$$(A+B)^3 - 3 AB (A+B) - (A^3 + B^3)$$

So, if we can find and $A$ and a $B$ such that

$$A B = \frac{25}{9}$$

and

$$A^3 + B^3 = - \frac{250}{27}$$

Then $A + B$ will satisfy the equation.

If we put $A^3 = a$ and $B^3 = b$, then we have:

$$a b = \left(\frac{25}{9}\right)^3$$

and

$$a + b = - \frac{250}{27} $$

This then gives rise to a quadratic equation for e.g. $a$:

$$a^2 +  \frac{250}{27} a +  \left(\frac{25}{9}\right)^3 = 0$$

The solution for $a$ is:

$$a = -\frac{125}{27}$$

And $b$ has the same solution:

$$b = -\frac{125}{27}$$

$A$ and $B$ are the cube roots of $a$ and $b$, respectively, but such that the product of $A$ and $B$ equals $ \frac{25}{9}$, so if we choose one of the 3 possible a cube root for $A$, the cube root we need to choose for $B$ is fixed.

The solution are thus given by:

$$y_n = A_n + B_n$$

for $n = 0,1,2$

where:

$$A_n = -\frac{5}{3}\exp\left(\frac{2 \pi i n}{3}\right)$$

$$B_n = -\frac{5}{3}\exp\left(\frac{-2 \pi i n}{3}\right)$$

We can simplify this as:

$$y_n = -\frac{10}{3}\cos\left(\frac{2 \pi n}{3}\right)$$

Therefore:

$$x_n = \frac{1}{3} -\frac{10}{3}\cos\left(\frac{2 \pi n}{3}\right)$$

The solutions are thus $x = -3$ and $x = 2$, the latter having a multiplicity of 2.

Comment: Getting rid of the quadratic term  by putting $ x=y+1/3$ is the first step of Cardano's method for this Q. In general, for $x^3+a x^2+b x+c=0$, substitute $x=y-a/3$.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know $-3$ and $2$ as roots, all that remains is to perform polynomial division for the corresponding linear factors:
$$
(x^3-x^2-8x+12):(x-2) = x^2+x-6
$$
and
$$
(x^2+x-6):(x+3)=x-2
$$
so that the third root is a repeat of the root $2$, giving it multiplicity $2$.